# mysql_fetch_object() warning

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to output a table from my database by using PHP, but shows "mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource".

```
// Connect to MySQL server
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

// Select database
mysql_select_db('bakery') or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "Select * From customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

echo "<table border=1>"; 
echo "<tr><td>custid</td>
<td>custname</td>
<td>ccn</td>
<td>phoneno</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>city</td>
<td>zip</td></tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
echo "<tr><td>$row->custid</td>
<td>$row->custname</td>
<td>$row->ccn</td>
<td>$row->phoneno</td>
<td>$row->address</td>
<td>$row->city</td>
<td>$row->zip</td></tr>"; 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Consider converting over to **mysqli** rather than **mysql** as it is deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: That's correct. @CarlMarkham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
```

It should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))  //<--- Pass the $result
```

As the error states... The `mysql_fetch_object` expects a resource , but you had passed a `string` (That was main error behind this)

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !